# How can I use setInterval() to automatically change slides on this React Spring project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, setinterval, react-spring

I implemented this React Spring component that gets a different slide after clicking on it. I would like to make it change automatically every X seconds by using the `setInterval` method.

I tried using `setInterval` but I'm not getting the desired results, because the `setInterval` function gets called multiple times and as the time increases the slides start changing like crazy until the browser freezes.

Here's the codesandbox original project https://codesandbox.io/embed/1y3yyqpq7q

And here's the code that I'm running currently

```
import { useTransition, animated } from 'react-spring'
import clientStyles from '../../styles/modules_scss/clients.module.scss'

const pages = [
    ({ style }) => <animated.div style={{ ...style, background: 'lightpink' }}>Andres Mejias</animated.div>,
    ({ style }) => <animated.div style={{ ...style, background: 'lightblue' }}>Andres Urdaneta</animated.div>,
    ({ style }) => <animated.div style={{ ...style, background: 'lightgreen' }}>Gustavo Abdelnour</animated.div>,
]

export default function SlideTransition() {
    const [index, set] = useState(0)
    const onClick = useCallback(() => set(state => (state + 1) % 3), [])
    const transitions = useTransition(index, p => p, {
        from: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(100%,0,0)' },
        enter: { opacity: 1, transform: 'translate3d(0%,0,0)' },
        leave: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(-50%,0,0)' },
    })
    return (
        <div className={clientStyles.simpleTransMain} onClick={setInterval(onClick, 3000)}> //Here's my approach
            {transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => {
                const Page = pages[item]
                return <Page key={key} style={props} />
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The best result I got was by wrapping `setInterval` in a anonymous function, and AFTER clicking the first slide I get a new slide every `3000ms`. I want this to happen without the need of clicking on the slide, as soon as the page loads.

`onClick={() => { setInterval(onClick, 3000) }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `setInterval` on every render so a new interval is getting created each time and your first one is still running. So you just get more and more added until it overloads the browser.

Since you want the interval to start before anything is clicked, add it to an effect so you can run it when the app mounts and clear it on unmount.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const interval_id = setInterval(onClick, 3000);
   return () => {
     // Stop the interval when the component unmounts. 
     // Otherwise it will keeep going and you will get an error.
     clearInterval(interval_id)
   }
}, []); // empty array of dependencies will cause it to run on mount and unmount only
```

Then just remove the `setInterval` in the `onClick` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

you can use useeffect to make the same effect as the life cycle "componentdidmount".
first, you cant call setinterval directly because it will keep causing a render, that's why you need to wrap it in an anonymous function, secondly, even if you use it this way, your onclick is changing the state and that will also cause a render each time without even finishing the first one, and keeping on doing this will cause your browser to freeze because of the large number of intervals that it created, so the best way is to clear your setinterval on unmount, so then each render will only have one interval to work with.